# CloudFormation cross-stack vs nested-stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm facing a decision to [Use Cross-Stack References to Export Shared Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#cross-stack) or to [Use Nested Stacks to Reuse Common Template Patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#nested) following AWS CloudFormation best practices.

However, they seem the same to me apart from a few differences:

- cross-stack uses `Fn::ImportValue`, templates are in one folder.
- nested-stack must be in S3, uses type `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` and `TemplateURL`.

There's no clear pros and cons between them as far as I could search.

My goal is to create a **parent stack** that passes some core variables like `stackName` to the **child stacks**, then the **child stacks** create the resources sharing some variables between them like `ARN` or `Policies`, using the `stackName` to name their resources like `stackNameDynamoDBTable`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use cross-stack references as it was created for your use case of passing between stacks.

Whereas nested stacks would work, it’s primary purpose is for reuse of modular components, like a template of a resource you use in lots of stacks to save copy pasting and updating the stacks independently.

Comment: I have a hard time believing nested stacks are about reuse. CloudFormation does everything in its power to make modularizing difficult, including that nested stacks manifest as a runtime resource instead of simply acting as an include/import mechanism. The only criteria I have for cross- vs nested-stack is whether you want to deploy all at once or individually, but even that is frustrating because sometimes you want to be able to do both and there is no good CloudFormation solution for that afaik.

Comment: This was a very good question, as I am facing a similar issue, but the value of using nest-stacks allows me to modularize a stack in order to keep it below file size limitations, but will be processed in sorts as one complete stack. At least that is what I am taking away for this discussion.

Answer (score 3):

**Nested stacks:**  if you need to manage your stacks from a single point, you should use nested stacks.
**example:** assume that you have load balancer configuration that you use for most of your stacks. Instead of copying and pasting the same configurations into your templates you can create a dedicated template for load balancer.

**cross-stack** : Alternatively, if you need to manage your stacks as separate entities, you should use cross-stack references.(AWS limits the number of VPCs you can create in an AWS region to five.)
**example :** You might have a network stack that includes a VPC, a security group, and a subnet. You want all public web apps to use these resources. By exporting the resources, you allow all stacks with public web applications to use them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the best of both worlds. The trick is to use cross-stack resource sharing but make it depend on a parameter that is passed using Nested stack.

Here's an example from how I used this, consider two stacks `IAMRoleStack` and `ComputeStack`. The former contains all the necessary IAM roles and the latter contains a bunch of Lambda functions that those roles are applied to.

```yaml
Resources:
  IAMCustomAdminRoleForLambda:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Policies:

Output:
  IAMRoleArnForLambda:
    Description: Returns the Amazon Resource Name for the newly created IAM Custom
      Role for Lambda function
    Value: !GetAtt 'IAMCustomAdminRoleForLambda.Arn'
    Export:
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-IAMRoleArnForLambda'

  StackName:
    Description: Returns name of stack after deployment
    Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}
```

As you can see I've exported the IAM role but it's `Name` depends on the stack name that is calculated once the stack is deployed. You can read more about exporting outputs in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html).

In the `ComputeStack`, I use this role by importing it.

```yaml
Resources:
  LambdaForCompute:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Role: !ImportValue
        Fn::Sub: ${StackNameOfIAMRole}-IAMRoleArnForLambda
```

The parent stack that "nests" both `ComputeStack` and `IAMRoleStack` orchestrates passing the stack name parameter.

```yaml
Resources:

  IAMRoleStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Ref IAMRoleStackURL

  ComputeStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Ref ComputeStackURL
      Parameters:
        StackNameOfIAMRole: !GetAtt IAMRoleStack.Outputs.StackName
```

I can't attest to best practice but this style allows me to pick and choose where I want orchestrated deployment and where I want to do the deployments individually.

I also want to point out that this kind of modularization based on type of resources is not very feasible for nested stacks. For e.g. in this scenario, if I had 10 different roles for 10 different Lambda functions, I would have to pass each of those 10 roles through parameters. Using this hybrid style, I only need to pass one parameter the stack name.

Answer (score 1):

With cross stacks, you pass a reference to a bunch existing components X to stacks A and B when you want A and B to **reuse these very same existing components**. With nested stacks, when you nest a nested stack Y in stacks C and D, Y shall create **a new set of components Y is describing** individually for C and for D.
It is similar to concepts 'passing by reference' and 'passing by value' in programming.